# trying to create a simple accordion - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Tags: jquery

This is my code for the accordion:

```
$('#faqlist li').click(function() {
    $('#faqlist li div').not('> div', this).slideUp(300, function() {
        $('> div', this).slideDown(300);
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="faqlist">
  <li><i class="icon-plus"></i>FAQ1
    <div id="faq1">FAQ1 content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the li, however, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null
```

Can anyone point me towards what's wrong?

Comment: what is `.not('> div')` ?

Comment: I think it's selecting everything that is an immediate child div of all the #faqlist li' but not of the '#faqlist li' that was clicked. Is that not correct?

Comment: I'm using Chrome too. I'll take another look, maybe for conflicting code, but the code is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) does not support a context as a parameter..

You can use

```
$('#faqlist li').click(function() {
    var current = $('>div', this);
    $('#faqlist li div').not(current).slideUp(300, function() {
        current.slideDown(300);
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/3aHaY/1/

Comment: mmm your code is not working in jsfiddle, at least not for me :/

Answer (score 0):

here is your code, corrected

http://jsfiddle.net/24PZd/

you might want to use:

```
.not($(this).next())
```